# Cantor-Bendixson rank of space of types

Tags: general-topology, model-theory

In Pillay's 'Geometric Stability Theory', it is said that if $\Phi(x)$ is a set of formulas, then the Cantor-Bendixson rank of the set of types consistent with $\Phi(x)$ is the minimum over the Cantor-Bendixson rank of the set of types consistent with some finite $\Phi'(x)\subseteq \Phi(x)$. So in other words:

$CB(\{p\in S_{\Delta}(\mathbb{M})\ |\ p\textrm{ consistent with } \Phi\}) =\min(\{CB(\{p\in S_{\Delta}(\mathbb{M})\ |\ p\textrm{ consistent with } \Phi'\})\ |\ \Phi'\subseteq \Phi \textrm{ finite}\})$.

Obviously, the proof of this statement needs some kind of compactness argument, but I have been unable to provide one, and I have found no source with a proof of this statement (though there are several which use it). Does anyone have an idea how to prove this?

Comment: It is important that $\Phi(x)$ is a *small* set of formulas, i.e. with parameters from a small subset of $\mathbb{M}$. To see why, consider the theory of an infinite set in the empty language, and let $\Delta = \{x=y\}$. Then $S_\Delta(\mathbb{M})$ consists of the realized types (one for each $a\in \mathbb{M}$), together with a single generic type. If $\Phi(x) = \{x\neq a\mid a\in \mathbb{M}\}$, then $\{p\mid p\text{ consistent with }\Phi\}$ is a singleton, so it has CB-rank $0$. But for any finite subset $\Phi'\subseteq \Phi$, $CB(\{p\mid p\text{ consistent with }\Phi'\}) = 1$.

Comment: I think the computation of Cantor-Bendixson rank is in $S_\Delta(\mathbb M)$. So even though $\{p : p \text { consistent with } \Phi\}$ is a singleton, it is the generic type and so has Cantor-Bendixson rank 1.

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan Right, so you could decide to always compute ranks in $S_\Delta(\mathbb{M})$ and make the definition that for any set of formulas $\Phi$, $R_\Delta(\Phi) = \max\{CB_{S_\Delta(\mathbb{M})}(p)\mid p\in [\Phi]\}$. But Pillay's definition (Def 3.2, p.31 of *GST*) is that $R_\Delta(\Phi)$ is the Cantor-Bendixson rank of the *subspace* $[\Phi]$ (and he only makes this definition for $\Phi$ small). Then he asserts $R_{\Delta}(\Phi) = \max\{CB_{S_\Delta(\mathbb{M})}(p)\mid p\in [\Phi]\}$ as something to be proven in Lemma 3.3.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Hmm, this does not smell right. Say the language has unary symbols $(P_i : i < \omega)$ and axioms $\forall x(P_{i+1}(x) \to P_i(x))$ and there are infinitely many elements satisfying $P_i$ but not $P_{i+1}$. Now let $\Phi = \{P_i(x) : i < \omega\}$ and let $\Delta$ be the set of all formulas. Then $[\Phi]$ consists of realised types and one generic type. So as a space it has CB-rank $1$. On the other hand for each finite $\Phi' \subset \Phi$ we have $[\Phi'] = [P_i]$ for some $i$, so has CB-rank $3$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan Yeah, good point (though I think $[P_i]$ has CB-rank $2$, not $3$). So Definition 3.2 in *GST* is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

There may be an easier proof, but I think the following works.

For ease of notation, let us denote $\{p \in S_\Delta(\mathbb M) : p \text { consistent with } \Phi\}$ by $[\Phi]$. Note that it is closed in $S_\Delta(\mathbb M)$ and therefore compact. Now let $\alpha = \min CB([\Phi'] : \Phi' \subseteq \Phi \text { finite}\}$. Let $\Phi'$ be a finite subset of $\Phi$ such that $CB([\Phi']) = \alpha$. Then for each finite $\Phi''$ with $\Phi' \subseteq \Phi'' \subseteq \Phi$, there is a type $p_{\Phi''} \in [\Phi'']$ with $CB(p_{\Phi''}) = \alpha$.

Now $\{p_{\Phi''} : \Phi' \subseteq \Phi'' \subseteq \Phi, \Phi'' \text { fiite}\}$ must be finite. Indeed, it is a subset of compact set $[\Phi']$ and has no limit points in $[\Phi']$. But then one of these $p_{\Phi''}$-s must be consistent with $\Phi$. This shows that $CB([\Phi]) \ge \alpha$. The other inequality is easy.

Comment: I think you need to be a little bit careful here (in particular, a correct argument needs to use somewhere that $\Phi$ is small, see my comment above). A priori you may have $p_{\Phi''}$ in $[\Phi'']$ for all $\Phi''$, such that $CB(p_{\Phi''}) = \alpha$ in each subspace $[\Phi'']$, but $CB(p_{\Phi''}) <\alpha$ in $[\Phi]$.

Comment: I dispute the argument that $\Phi$ needs to be small. I think the confusion comes from where you calculate the Cantor-Bendixson rank. If you have a space $X$ and $Y \subseteq X$, then you can define $CB(Y) = \sup\{CB(y) : y \in Y\}$. This of course can be different from the Cantor-Bendixson rank of $Y$ as a topological space. (The notation is very confusing indeed.) But I think this is what we do in model theory, e.g. when defining the Morley rank (or indeed the $\Delta$-rank) of a formula through Cantor-Bendixson rank.

Comment: I agree that this is a reasonable way to go, but it's not the way that Pillay chooses to go in *GST* (see my comment above).

Answer (score 1):

In light of the discussion in the comments, I think Definition 3.2 in *Geometric Stability Theory* is incorrect. Instead, you should take the statement you're trying to prove as the definition!

Fix a set of formulas $\Delta$. For any set of formulas $\Phi$, define $[\Phi] = \{p\in S_\Delta(\mathbb{M})\mid p\text{ is consistent with }\Phi\}$, and for a single formula $\phi$, define $[\phi] = [\{\phi\}]$.

Bottom-up approach:

- For a formula $\phi$, define $R_\Delta(\phi) = CB([\phi])$, the Cantor-Bendixson rank of the subspace $[\phi]\subseteq S_{\Delta}(\mathbb{M})$.
- For a set of formulas $\Phi$, define $R_\Delta(\Phi) = \min\{R_\Delta([\bigwedge\Phi'])\mid \Phi'\subseteq \Phi\text{ finite}\}$.

Top-down approach:

- For a complete $\Delta$-type $p$, define $R_\Delta(p) = CB(p)$, the Cantor-Bendixson rank of the point $p\in S_\Delta(\mathbb{M})$.
- For a set of formulas $\Phi$, define $R_\Delta(\Phi) = \max\{R_\Delta(p)\mid p\in [\Phi]\}$.

It's a good exercise to show that these two definitions are equivalent.